# Determine return type for object returned from a task

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which should retrieve atrifacts from maven repo, extract them to temp dir and copy some file to destinatiom folder. Currently it works pretty fine - artifacts are downloaded using maven_artifact task. But some requirements have changed and I need to use get_url task now. After changing to get_url the whole rest of the playbook is broken because object returned from maven_artifact and get_url are of different types. How to determine what type with what fields is getting returned from a task?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

No matter which ansible module you use there is the option to create variables from the output of the task by using `register`.

The ansible documentation states which return values are available to you when doing so. Here for example are the return values for the `get_url` module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html

In that case you may do something like the following to retrieve the status code of the `get_url` module:

```yaml
- name: Download foo.conf
  get_url:
    url: http://example.com/path/file.conf
    dest: /etc/foo.conf
    mode: '0440'
  register: my_result

- name: Print status code of get_url
  debug:
    var: my_result.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Each module returns an object of a different type.
There Is no way within Ansible to identify the type of a registered variable (i.e. what attributes you can read from it) however, a module will always return an object of the same type.

The return values of a module are listed at the bottom of that modules documentation page.